# What is wrong here? In my code (Inserting Image into Database - C#)

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am trying to insert an image in my access database from C# winform. I am using the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\db1.mdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, Image) VALUES ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', @img)";
        byte[] yourPhoto = imageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", yourPhoto);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image iImage)
    {
        MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

When I run the code  it show me an error: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`
What is wrong here in my code? I can successfully insert text to the fields of database by using the same query.

Comment: http://lh4.ggpht.com/_eknxl1DkWrU/Sd9xo_Pt8PI/AAAAAAAAA-s/cQHUuxPpBeM/s1600-h/UploadImage%5B3%5D.jpg

Comment: still not working after adding '@' with the img.

Comment: what are the data types of your columns? Are you sure 'Column4' is a valid value for Price column?

Comment: Yeah! I am sure it is because I set it to string because Price should save with its unit like: 25 PKR or 3 USD etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Image` is a reserved word, so I assume you should put this word in quotes or square brackets in the SQL query.

Comment: `Image` is still a reserved word to the Jet Engine. Is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266 not applicable here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and add parameters to your other column:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\db1.mdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price,[Image]) VALUES (@Product,@Manufacturer,@Description,@Price,@Image)";
        byte[] yourPhoto = imageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", "yourProductValue");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer","yourManufacturerValue");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "yourDescriptionValue");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price","yourPriceValue");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", yourPhoto);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image iImage)
{
    MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try entering img as @img in your sql query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, Image) VALUES ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', @img);";
```

**EDIT:** also end your sql query with a '**;**'. I added it in the query above.

Comment: actually I am using the same code you have mentioned, '@' is left in copying the code this site. I edited it.

Comment: Yes all i did was include the '@' symbol in your code. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forget to add an @-sign before your parameter:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, Image) VALUES ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', img)";
```

should be

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, Image) VALUES ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', @img)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the value for parameter "@img", but your query only mentions "img", so instead you need to set the query text thus:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, Image) VALUES ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', @img )";
```

Answer (score 0):

may be some input data is not in good form, leading to Sql injection . so i suggest you to try like this . with parametrized query. also try to give some good descriptive name to your columns. Image will be ambigious. as it will be treated as keyword.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Manufacturer, Description, Price, [Image]) VALUES (@column1, @column2, @column3, @column4, @img )";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", yourval);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", yourval);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column3", yourval);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column4", yourval);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", yourPhoto);
```

Comment: remove the quotes around the @ColumnX parameters on the right part of the CommandText :)